# Delphi - run javascript in a webbrowser

Tags: javascript, delphi, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to call the OnChange event of “Select” ? (Delphi - WebBrowser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724822/how-to-call-the-onchange-event-of-select-delphi-webbrowser)

Hi,

I'm loading a web page into a Twebrowser in delphi, the webpage has a form with a drop down. I can get my program to select the item id like in the drop down menu but the select option has a onchange event how can i fire the onchange event in delphi **without using execScript('yourfunctioname()', 'JavaScript');**

heres the select with the onChnage event

```
<select align="left" id="carrierNameDropDown_UNSHIPPEDITEMS" onChange="MYO.ES.OtherCarrierToggle (this, 'UNSHIPPEDITEMS' )">
          <option value="0"  selected="1" >Select</option>
              <option value="Chronopost"  >Chronopost</option>
              <option value="City Link"  >City Link</option>
              <option value="DHL"  >DHL</option>
              <option value="DPD"  >DPD</option>
              <option value="Deutsche Post"  >Deutsche Post</option>
              <option value="Fastway"  >Fastway</option>
              <option value="FedEx"  >FedEx</option>
              <option value="GLS"  >GLS</option>
              <option value="GO!"  >GO!</option>
              <option value="Hermes Logistik Gruppe"  >Hermes Logistik Gruppe</option>
              <option value="La Poste"  >La Poste</option>
              <option value="Parcelforce"  >Parcelforce</option>
              <option value="Parcelnet"  >Parcelnet</option>
              <option value="Poste Italiane"  >Poste Italiane</option>
              <option value="Royal Mail"  >Royal Mail</option>
              <option value="SDA"  >SDA</option>
              <option value="Smartmail"  >Smartmail</option>
              <option value="TNT"  >TNT</option>
              <option value="Target"  >Target</option>
              <option value="UPS"  >UPS</option>
              <option value="Yodel"  >Yodel</option>

          <option value="Other">
              Specify carrier:
          </option>
        </select>
```

I got it to work by doing:

```
if EmbeddedWB1.Document <> nil then begin
if EmbeddedWB1.Document.QueryInterface(IHTMLDocument3,docb) = S_OK then begin
elb := docb.getElementById('carrierNameDropDown_UNSHIPPEDITEMS');
if elb <> nil then begin
(elb as IHTMLSelectElement).value := 'Parcelforce';
OleVariant (elb as IHTMLElement). FireEvent ('onchange');
end;
```

Comment: thanks Ian! although i tried it and keep getting the error: delphi could not complete the operation due to error 80020101 :(

Comment: I think i might be able to use FireEvent("onchange") but im not sure how to use it...still looking..

Comment: i think its something like this but does anyone know how to use it? OleVariant(yourIHTMLElement).FireEvent('onchange') ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
uses 
  MSHTML;

procedure TBrowserPageIE.Test;
var
  doc : IHTMLDocument3;
  el  : IHTMLElement;
  v   : OleVariant;
begin
  if FBrowser.Document <> nil then begin
    if FBrowser.Document.QueryInterface(IHTMLDocument3,doc) = S_OK then begin
      el := doc.getElementById('carrierNameDropDown_UNSHIPPEDITEMS');

      if el <> nil then begin
        (el as IHTMLSelectElement).value := 'UPS';
        (el as IHTMLElement3).FireEvent('onchange', v);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

and this with late binding

```
procedure TBrowserPageIE.Test;
var
  doc : IHTMLDocument3;
  el  : OleVariant;
  v   : OleVariant;
begin
  if FBrowser.Document <> nil then begin
    if FBrowser.Document.QueryInterface(IHTMLDocument3,doc) = S_OK then begin
      el := doc.getElementById('carrierNameDropDown_UNSHIPPEDITEMS');
      el.value := 'UPS';
      el.FireEvent('onchange', v);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: hey matthias, i tried it but it came back with Undeclared identifier: 'IHTMLElement3' what am i doing wrong?

Comment: hmm ive just been searching around maybe this is a way of doing it: OleVariant (selectField as IHTMLElement). FireEvent ("onchange");   but how to use it?

Comment: Added alternative solution with late binding to the answer.